# Logging user activity in a Silverlight web application: What if user changes their system's datetime?

Tags: silverlight, telerik

I have a web application that logs several user actions. In addition, one of the more critical aspects of this app uses the Telerik Scheduler component to schedule access to other areas of the application. This can be easily spoofed by changing the datetime or timezone in your Windows settings. Does anyone have any tips on ensuring users can't "pull a fast one" on us?

Answer (score 2):

You could grab the current system time from a server during app start-up and compare it to the current client time and store the difference. Then whenever you need a time value, use the client time adjusted by the difference. If users are likely to adjust their system's time during app use, you could fetch the system time before every important operation, or repeatedly fetch it at some specified time interval.

Comment: I should also mention: for this to work properly the precision required for your timestamps must be > latency between server and client.